# Webservices for GPS (Upload on DB and display it)

Tags: openlayers-2, gps, web-service

i'm doing an application where my users would be able to upload their gps tracks. My idea is to put their tracks on mysql database and display it on appropriate map.
Question:How can i do that? My first idea is use garmin webservice to upload data, and then, show that on a map using openlayers lib. This is a good approach? What direction should i take?

thanks in advance

Comment: Would the Garmin Web Services API of interest? http://developer.garmin.com/web-products/web-services/

Comment: That is what i've referred. There are others approaches? garmin webservice is a good one?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to start from scratch or are you perfectly willing to use an existing program? [phpMyGPX](http://phpmygpx.tuxfamily.org/phpmygpx.php) seems to do pretty much everything you want. It's written in PHP and the tracks are stored in a MySQL DB. It's **open source**, too. Here's its full feature list:

- **stores all gpx files, waypoints and trackpoints in database**
- tag GPX files and search for keywords
- download stored GPX files from data base
- filter trackpoints and waypoints
- generate GPX from filtered trackpoints or waypoints
- statistics for each GPX
- **preview birdview (map) image of track/route**
- images of elevation and speed profiles for GPX
- store bookmarks for your favourite map locations
- show geotagged photos on a map
- automatic geotagging of photos during import, based on GPX
- different map styles and overlays
- **uses OSM tile servers to show online map with GPX overlay**
- simple proxy for caching map tiles included
- batch import for photos and GPX files
- installation and upgrade wizard
- highly customizable via config file
- available languages: Dutch, English, French, German, Spanish

[image]

You can check the [demo](http://phpmygpx.tuxfamily.org/demo/) if you want to explore it more. If you're really intent on writing your own then you can also check the source code and use it as a reference. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I use phpMyadmin for normal data like username, messages and other stuff, i would like to include gpx from each user. I didn't know phpmygpx i will take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what language you intend to write this app in, but i wrote a rather similar app in Java a year ago or so, mineturer.org. This lets the user upload a GPX track, and then i pars it using a SAXparser and the GPX schema. The tracks are stored in a PostGIS database, and displayed on an OpenLayers map.

Not too proud of the code anymore (guess I would have written it in Python now), but the code is open source and available at https://bitbucket.org/atlefren/gpsorganizer if you want to have a look at it.